# How can I fix a rig/bones whose appearance has changed from simple lines to complex?

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

Why did it change from how it looks in the image on the left with light-colored lines to the one on the right with big green arrows?

[image: example of the error]

Answer (score 1):

In your *Data* panel, under *Bone Collections*, you can make some collections visible or invisible, the octahedral bones you show are the one that are controlled and that deform the mesh:

[image]

In previous versions, *Bone Collections* were *Layers*:

[image]

Comment: for some reason, my blender does not have that option. at data, I have the skeleton with 2 options one for pose position and one for rest position. right below are layers: with dots that are supposed to be checked and in another dropdown below I have "bone groups".... I think it is because I'm still using 3.6 while on my laptop I have the same appearance as yours..... this is so confusing one other detail I can notice is that under "Rig Layers" the names are gone...in my understanding these are linked to the "Layers" below the pose position and rest position

Comment: In 3.6 it should be in the same panel under "Layer"

Comment: hmmm you are right by selecting or unhiding the option ORG these green thick bones are shown ... however In one of the versions of the same file even when I unmark ORG the colored lines won't come back and in the previous version of Blender it does not even have the ORG option...or it is elsewhere this is confusing... I would love to understand what key or shortcut I pressed by accident to cause this.. I'm about to pull my hair out

Comment: Hmm, I could not find the "Layer" you are referring to.  thank you for your help  I appreciate you trying to help me figure this out. By any chance...do you know if there is some sort of redo bottom to remake the rig with the meta rig? I tried the "regenerate rig option but it did not work...remains to hide the controls as displayed at the right (with thin colored lines)   ... once again a million thanks

Comment: @EstraviusLothar Be careful when moving between versions in Blender. You may need to re-rig your character when switching versions. Check [this](https://blenderartists.org/t/backwards-compatibility-for-3-6-and-below-rigify-scripts/1487219) for more information.

Comment: @MrA you are right I have to be careful when switching between versions but I swear I was not changing when my problem started happening. I was fixing axes in the fingers when suddenly the way the bones changed to this unfriendly version without colors and no names at the "Rig layers" menu...no Root no face no torso..I'm still trying to find what was the cause of my problem because if it happens again I might lose a progression. I mean I know I have to save every so on and the incrementals are a good way.. but...I would love to know how to resolve or prevent

Answer (score 1):

The armature object has three modes. Depending on the mode, the custom bone shapes and colors may or may not be active. I list what you should expect in each mode below.

1. **Object Mode**

- The armature object (all bones) will show up in the default selection colors.
- The bones will have their custom shapes.

2. **Pose Mode**

- The bones will have their custom colors and custom shapes.

3. **Edit Mode**

- In 3.x, the bones will show up in the default selection colors. In 4.x, the bones will have their custom colors (for *Edit Mode*).
- The bones will have their default shape which is set on the armature data (`Object Data Properties > Viewport Display > Display As`).

---

Basically, when you switch to *Edit Mode* (to edit the roll of the bones), it is normal to see the bones in their default shape. The bones will switch back to their custom shapes once you switch back to *Object Mode* or *Pose Mode*.

Comment: Wow thank you for this answer. I am going to try it :) . I'm going to create a copy to check this out. sorry if I did not answer before...since Christmas was so close I had certain things to do and I stopped checking this topic

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: :'( It didn't work. I opened the drop-down menu with different options and tried switching between them, but I couldn't recover the colored lines. I can still move the bones and theoretically create poses, but I have a sense that the file may be unrecoverable. As a workaround, I continued with a previous file.